# How can I write this raw query using Laravel's Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to write this raw query using Eloquent. I have tried using ->whereRaw but it shows error due to special characters in it.

```
SELECT id,shipping_email FROM orders WHERE 1 AND `shipping_email` NOT REGEXP '^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,63}$' AND id = '<>'
```

Help is appreciated...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got answer, I have tried these codes..

```
\Model\Order::query()
    ->select('id', 'shipping_email')
    ->whereRaw("`shipping_email` NOT REGEXP ?", ["^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,63}$"])
    ->get();
```

Comment: I believe you can also wrap not regexp in a regular where clause. where('shipping_email', 'not regexp', '^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,63}$')

Comment: Thank you for another suggestion... I will try this.